# Creating a custom archiving program?

Tags: windows, file, zip, archive

Ok, so you know those archiving programs like 7z and winrar, yeah. does anyone know how i can make my own archiving program with a custom file format. i know it may seem like a dumb question but i'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so hard 
If you know java I can give you a link to simple java library
https://github.com/kamranzafar/jtar/
The API is very easy but it only archive it do not compress it
and you want compress it there built in zip in java library